# How to show a interface method in an implementation class using Visio UML diagram

Tags: inheritance, uml, visio

I have an interface, e.g. `IPerson` which has a method: `public Date DOB()`, and an implementation class: `Student`. How can I make the `DOB()` method show in the `Student` class without just typing in the operation/method name?

Most importantly when I add the `Student` class object to a sequence diagram, I'd like to have the `DOB()` method ready for me to select, when passing a message to the object.

All of the above works when `IPerson` is not a interface but a concrete class, but I think it should work for the interface case too, and anyway, the methods defined in an interface should be able to be shown in an implementation class.

I'm using Visio 2003, but I guess it should generally work across different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make methods in a interface 'fall through' to the implementation class, the implementation class has to 'realize' the interface by connecting the 'realization link' to the interface.